# cannot concatenate str and list objects

Tags: python, arcpy, geoprocessing

I'm trying to rename a group of rasters to "I1986_" + [The 1st 3 letters of the raster]. For example, if a raster is named "Raster1", the output would be "I1986_Ras".

I've tried including str() functions in a couple places as well as .join in the tool's out data parameter but end up generating other errors.  If I don't use rList variable in the Rename function and use the rasters variable instead, the script will rename the first file in the directory but then say i1986_xxx already exists.  Any ideas?

```
arcpy.env.workspace = DIRECTORY
rList = arcpy.ListRasters()
for rasters in rList:
    arcpy.Rename_management(rList, "I1986_" + rList[0:3])
```

Comment: That will happen if any rasters have the same value for the first three characters in their filename. This would happen if you manually renamed them as well. You'll either have to check if the new name exists first and come up with a different naming scheme, or accept that not all will be renamed. E.g. if rList = ['tom1.jpg', 'tom2.jpg', 'fred1.jpg'], the first 3 characters of tom1 and tom2 are the same. tom1 will be renamed, tom2 will give the error you're experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like below. rList is a list. It will concatenate with a string, but proabably not as you are expecting.

```
>>> l1 = ['cat','dog','mouse','monkey','elephant']
>>>'I1986_' + str(l1[0:3])
"I1986_['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']"
```

Python creates a string representation of the 1st 3 elements in the list. That is why the 1st iteration succeeds, but then the next fails and reports that the object already exists. This would rename all of your objects to the same name.

You're already looping through the list, so use your looping variable to concatenate with the elements of the list.

```
for raster in rList:
    newName = 'I1986_{}'.format(raster[0:3])
    arcpy.Rename_management(raster, newName)
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This seems to answer whatever he is asking.

Comment: thank you recurvata, your solution answered my question.  I don't know when or if I would have figured out your solution of declaring newName and the parameters you set for that variable.

Comment: Well, @JasonT deserves some credit, edited my answer for more detail.